# CPU Fan size for ZOTAC IONITX-G-E Intel Atom 330 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, cpu-cooler

I have had the [ZOTAC ION-ITX G Series [IONITX-G-E]](http://www.zotacusa.com/zotac-ion-itx-g-series-ionitx-g-e.html)  for about a year and a half and have had no problems until a few days ago. All the sudden the CPU Fan sounds awful, and i can hear it from the next room. Since everything else works fine i Figure i will just replace the fan, but i don't know what size it is. I checked the manual and online and can't find anything.

Anybody happen to know what size the cpu fan is on this board?

Comment: The CPU is cooled passively. The chipset lies under the fan.

Comment: @Dennis that makes since actually, never looked at it very close. You wouldn't happen to know the size would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer themselves are not so forthright with minutia such as individual fan size within the stock heatsink. ATOM processors are socket 441 CPUs and atom heatsinks appear to typically use 40mm fans. However, it might be more painless to simply buy the entire heatsink apparatus for your socket than replace the fan itself.

Of course, if all else fails...

[image]

Comment: I thought about measuring, but I am the guy in the family that can measure something 10 times and get 10 different measurements. Not sure what is wrong with me, I'm usually good with tools, but tape measures and rulers somehow elude me. I'll keep looking and if I can't not find anything I will go ahead a attempt to measure it.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Ergh. Curse Newegg! I changed the post. =)